# setup.py install_requires built-in package: include or omit?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-wheel

I have a python package I made. It uses `datetime` in multiple places. I notice that on a brand-new python install, I can do `import datetime` without issue. Thus, python comes with `datetime` built-in.

If I put `datetime` in my setup.py as one of the items in `install_requires`, it appears to download the pypi package `datetime`, even though the builtin package is already available. In some cases, such as with `multiprocessing`, the pypi package might require extra things (in the case of the pypi`multiprocessing`, it requires `gcc-c++` to be installed on my CentOS, while the builtin `multiprocessing` has no such requirements).

Questions:

- Should I include builtin packages under `install_requires` if I use them?
- Is there an easier way of seeing which packages are builtin and which aren't other than creating a new `virtualenv` and trying to import things?
- Who owns the pypi versions of these builtin packages? Is it some random person, or are these vetted packages provided by the python core team? (I know arbitrary packages can be provided by random people, but I can't figure out if that's true for the builtin packages that are also available on pypi.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it appears to download the pypi package datetime

Not exactly. It downloads a package called `DateTime` with top-level name `DateTime`, not `datetime`.

> Should I include builtin packages under `install_requires` if I use them?

No. `install_requires` is intended to list external, 3rd-party packages, not the builtin ones, not the standard ones.

> Is there an easier way of seeing which packages are builtin and which aren't?

One is `datetime`, the other is `DateTime`.

> Who owns the pypi versions of these builtin packages?

The page https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/ name the author: Zope Foundation and Contributors. And list the current maintainers. The homepage listed is https://github.com/zopefoundation/DateTime

Comment: 1. The wheel I download is `datetime`, but the package I import from it is called `DateTime`, is that correct? 2. Regarding differentiating, I meant, "How do I tell which packages to list in `install_requires`? Is there a way to know that a package is builtin other than making a virtualenv and checking if it's available?"

Comment: Nevermind on question 1. I see that it is in fact called `DateTime`, it's just that pip is case insensitive and doesn't care if I type `pip install dAtEtImE`, it'd still get me to that project. Still confused on point 2, however.

Comment: Builtin and standard commands are listed in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html Choose the proper version of Python — every new release adds (and often obsoletes) modules.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easier way of seeing which packages are builtin and which aren't > other than creating a new virtualenv and trying to import things?

It seems there isn't a builtin way to do this, but rather than trying to import things, you can run `pkgutil.iter_modules()` to get an iterable with importable modules, which on fresh virtualenv should give you only builtin modules. Then you can compare that list with your own list of used packages.

For example, in a new virtualenv:

```
import pkgutil
fulldeps = ['datetime', 'multiprocessing', 'tensorflow']
builtin_modules = [module.name for module in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
real_deps = [module for module in fulldeps if module not in builtin_modules]

print(real_deps)
```

```
['tensorflow']
```